# Is there a pre-existing implementation of the General Number Field Sieve (GNFS) in Python?

Tags: python

Is there any inbuilt or online Implementation of GNFS factoring in Python? I need a version that can easily be used to factor integers in other programs so I would need to import and preferably is comparable with or only needs minimal change to work with Python 3. I need this to factor (multiple) numbers of over 90 digits in length and elliptic curve factorization is too slow for the purpose.

I have checked online and could only find Perl and C++ implementations.
If not is there any online resource that could guide me step by step to my own implementation of this algorithm?

Comment: Asking for libraries or other tools on SO is generally considered as off topic. I think that implementations of GNFS are generally done in low level languages such as C or C++. IMHO, you should choose one of those, and just develop an Python interface to it either directly or using SWIG or SIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pearl wrapper for GGNFS (c implementation) was rewritten into python by Brian Gladman.
Look for *factmsieve.py*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [primefac](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/primefac)

which works this way:

```
python3 -m primefac 24 ! 1 - 38 ! 1 +
```

and in seconds you will have the results:

[image]

Comment: example doesn't work for me :(

Comment: look @ArduinoBen, I added a picture for you. It works

Answer (score 0):

See This Code!

```
from primefac import primefac
def Factorize(n):
    B = True
    try:
        Function = primefac(n)
        while B:
            print(next(Function))
     except:
         B = False
```